# Regex capturing too much

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, wikipedia

I have a problem with a .NET regex that I need to create for my AutoWikiBrowser bot on Wikipedia.

The example is rather long, but I need an even longer regex to find up to 14 language indication templates (2-3 letters inside double curly brackets, e.g. `{{ab}}`) and merge them into a single template (e.g. `{{ab}} {{cd}} {{ef}} {{gh}}` => `{{mul|ab|cd|ef|gh}}`

Here is my regex:

Find:
`\{\{ *(ab|cd|ef|gh) *\}\} *\{\{ *(ab|cd|ef|gh) *\}\} *(\{\{ *(ab|cd|ef|gh) *\}\})* *(\{\{ *(ab|cd|ef|gh) *\}\})* *(\{\{ *(ab|cd|ef|gh) *\}\})* *(\{\{ *(ab|cd|ef|gh) *\}\})*`

Replace:
`{{mul|$1|$2|$4|$6|$8|$10}}`

It is actually working as intended, except if templates are not separated by a space, then the last templates aren't captured properly. You can see the problem with the first line of the test string here: https://regex101.com/r/nMUg0J/2

I think I should use a lookaround, but I can't even find where the problem is.

Note that this regex will create templates with useless pipes if there isn't enough templates to marge, but I'll use this other regex after the first one to remove them: https://regex101.com/r/MuIiWS/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly more easily achieved by using a replacement function with a single regex, but if you are restricted to regex only, possibly an easier solution is to first replace the `}}{{` between templates with a `|` and then add the `mul|` at the beginning of any multiple lanugage template. So first, replace:

```
(?<=ab|cd|ef|gh) *}} *{{ *(?=ab|cd|ef|gh)
```

with `|` (demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KqHX30/2)), and then replace

```
(?<={{)(?=(?:ab|cd|ef|gh)\|)
```

with `mul|` (demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IQnSqX/2))

Comment: Thanks @Nick, this is an interesting way to solve the problem, but your first regex doesn't work if there are multiple spaces between the templates, nor if there are spaces inside the template (the last lines of the test string).
This is quite important because it can happen sometimes, and I want to run my bot to be able to run without supervision.
An other solution is to first replace the groupes of 14 templates, then 13, then 12, etc.
But I'd prefer a simpler solution, because there are 373 possible language codes, so the regex I'll use is really huge.

Comment: I am tired sorry, it's late here.
It works better if ``` *``` are added: https://regex101.com/r/fv5i4q/2 .
Only the last space before the curly brackets is left, this is much better than my previous try.
I'll make more tests tomorrow, thank you again and have a nice day/night!

Comment: @oli_vi_er Giant oops. I put the correct regex (with all the `*`) in the question but somehow managed to paste in the wrong link. I've corrected that. If you want/need to get rid of that final space you could replace `(?<=ab|cd|ef|gh) +(?=}})` with (empty string)

Answer (score 1):

So, thanks to @Nick who solved the problem I raised above, and also the tip in this post comments (I edited the following regexes in accordance).

I'll just talk a bit some issues I encountered that are specific to Wikipedia where I made the edits :

If the preceding template ends or the following one begins with letters that correspond to the set of letters in the regex, their culry brackets are modified altogether with the ones between the language indication templates : https://regex101.com/r/yY5H0C/1

It is then neccessary to encapsulate all the language codes in `\b` tags : https://regex101.com/r/YcZZVQ/2

The complete process taking in account the surrounding wikicode needs
4 steps:

1. replacing the curly brackets between the language templates by pipes: https://regex101.com/r/ssQxSO/2
2. adding the template name in front: https://regex101.com/r/NfohdT/4
3. removing the potential leftover space at the end of the template, and adding a potential space between the next template/link/text: https://regex101.com/r/tVfxG8/2
4. adding a potential space between the previous template/link/text: https://regex101.com/r/jw6Lt8/2

The last two operations are "non-cosmetic" and do not affect what the reader of the article will see, but it makes the wikicode cleaner.

Thanks again to @Nick for his idea and his regexes, which have enabled me to deal with over 17,000 pages with problems in Wikipedia in French, and will no doubt facilitate future maintenance operations of this type when the problem occurs again.

Comment: Wow, what a painful process - good to see you got it all working. Note you could simplify your regex a bit by using `(?<=\b(?:ab|cd|ef|fg)\b)` rather than `(?<=\bab\b|\bcd\b|\bef\b|\bfg\b)`. Please feel free to accept your own answer rather than mine given that it is more complete.

Comment: Damn, I tried to put the \b tags around the lookaround and didn't think about adding a non capturing group for them instead -_- Anyway, the performance isn't an issue, as my bot is rigged to make about 6 edits per minute.
Your answer is the good one for the question I asked, not the task I had to do on Wikipédia, so it should be the correct answer.

Comment: @Nick I have a problem: some templates use the same letters as the language codes, but in upper case (for example {{AE}}). If these templates have parameters, they are processed by the 2nd regex (which adds mul| if a language code followed by a pipe is found). Is there a simple way of avoiding this, bearing in mind that the first letter of the language indication templates found in the articles can be in lower or upper case? I have a list of the upper case/non-language related templates, but I think it would be better to deal with all possible occurrences.

Comment: Oh that's horrible. I don't think there's a simple way around it, you'll need to do something like `(?<=\b(?:[Aa]b|[Cc]d|[Ee]f|\b[Ffg])\b)`; or well I guess it would be more simple to have the second regex check that what is after the pipe is *also* a valid language code e.g. https://regex101.com/r/SuKvBb/1

Comment: @Nick yea, I think that adding a pipe is the best solution, but now a lot of possible false-positives come to my mind, haha. I guess it's a good thing to be a bit OCD with regexes ;p.

Comment: Well, you know what they say about a man with one problem who decides to use regex to solve it... :)